# Why do my dates/times appear in a shifted timezone?

Tags: google-apps-script, timezone

I am working in the UK.  My spreadsheet timezone is set to GMT+00:00, locale to United Kingdom.  My Calendar (which is what the spreadsheet is 'feeding') is set to GMT+00:00 United Kingdom Time.

Why, therefore, do all my Dates and Times come out in the format "Mon Apr 26 2021 19:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"?  The data is being entered in a Google Form (which has no settings for Time Zones) and therefore has to be entered separately as a date and a time.  I am trying to combine these values within the spreadsheet prior to exporting them as an event in Calendar, but this time shift is driving me mad!

I'm sure I am not the first (or the last!) to experience these problems.  Can anybody advise, please?

Comment: Perhaps your script time zone is wrong or perhaps your using a format string in formatDate that's incorrect.  But since you didn't post any code we can only guess. Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also in the UK and I've struggled with this, too. Although your spreadsheet is in the UK timezone, the script you are using is not. To change the timezone of your script:

1. Click on [Use legacy editor] button on the top right hand corner of
   the script editor
2. In the legacy editor, go to File > Project properties
   and set your timezone in there
3. Switch back to the new editor

If anyone knows how to configure this without changing to the legacy editor, please let me know, too.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you - solved the problem at a stroke!